# How to auto set-upstream when pushing with push.default current?

Tags: git, git-push, git-track

I used to delete my branches automatically with the indication of `git fetch -p` plus some git plumbing command¹, and matching for a `[gone]` pattern then deleting matched branches.

Some repositories I work with enforce squashing pull requests, therefore merged commit are never made locally, and I have no way of linking content of new commits and contents of my local branches.

Some times ago I switched to `push.default current`, and the feature is really better than `push.default upstream` or `simple`.

Since a few days, I noticed all my branches aren't deleted anymore ; and that comes from the fact when pushing, the upstream is "guessed" but never *set*.

If I manually set the upstream of a branch (through --set-upstream-to), then I can see my trim script working again ; but that defies the purpose of using push.default set to *current*.

```sh
$ git switch -c my-branch
Switched to a new branch 'my-branch'
$ git push 
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: ...
$ git branch -vv
  main      3b3a404 [origin/main] Merge branch 'test-push' into 'main'
* my-branch 3b3a404 Merge branch 'test-push' into 'main'
$ git push -u origin my-branch 
Branch 'my-branch' set up to track remote branch 'my-branch' from 'origin'.
Everything up-to-date
$ git branch -vv
  main      3b3a404 [origin/main] Merge branch 'test-push' into 'main'
* my-branch 3b3a404 [origin/my-branch] Merge branch 'test-push' into 'main'
$ git push -d origin my-branch # this is done automatically after merging
$ git fetch -p
...
 - [deleted]         (none)     -> origin/my-branch
$ git branch -vv
  main      3b3a404 [origin/main] Merge branch 'test-push' into 'main'
* my-branch 3b3a404 [origin/my-branch: gone] Merge branch 'test-push' into 'main'
                                       ^... this is what helps me automatically trimming merged branches
```

Is there a way to *automate* that upstream setting to the *pushed-to branch* without actually typing it ?

*I actually tested to plug a pre-push hook, but if the branch does not exist, then set-upstream cannot work ; and post-push hooks don't exist.*

*Actually, my end goal is to delete merged-squashed branches, but I see no better candidate that checking if the remote is gone to verify that ; since I have got no garantees of history rewrites*

<sub>1: `git for-each-ref --format '%(upstream:track) %(refname)' refs/heads | awk ' $1 == "[gone]" { sub("refs/heads/", "", $2) ; print $2 }'`</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your `push.default` is set to `current`, `git push -u` alone (without the `... origin my-branch`) will create the remote branch *and* set your local branch to track that remote branch.

---

*additional note* : `%(refname:short)` (in `git for-each-ref --format`) will display the branch name you are used to

Comment: I'm keeping the answer 24h open before accepting your answer